# How to modify values in object list in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How can I remove "(LIVE)" from each value in numbers

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "601bc57b1ab1854675870d24"
  },
  "name": "Some name",
  "numbers": [
    "APHYD00(LIVE)",
    "APHYD11(LIVE)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you want to **update** the numbers or for **projection** to hide `(LIVE)` word?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      numbers: {
        $map: {
          input: "$numbers",
          in: {
            $replaceAll: {
              input: "$$this",
              find: "(LIVE)",
              replacement: ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

or if you need to **update** existing values

```
db.collection.updateMany({ numbers: { $exists: true } }, [
  {
    $set: {
      numbers: {
        $map: {
          input: "$numbers",
          in: {
            $replaceAll: {
              input: "$$this",
              find: "(LIVE)",
              replacement: ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qhq9b97ZXSQ)